# Defining a comparator for a quadratic function object

Tags: java, overriding

This is my assignment, 
a) Write a quadraticFunction that represents a quadratic ax^2 + bx + c with int coeffients a, b, c. Provide a constructor with 3 int parameters for a, b, c. Provide a method double valueAt(double x) returns the value of this quadratic function at x. Also provide a toString method.

b) override the equals method quadraticmethod class. two quadraticfunction should be considered equal if their respective coeffiecients are equal

c) Make the function objects comparable. The compareTo should first compare 1 if equal compare b if equal compare c

d) Define a comparator class for comparing two QuadraticFunction objects. Provide two constructors:  a no-argss constructor and a constructor that takes 1 double parameter. When a comparator is created by the no-args constructor, it should compare two quadraticFunction based on their values at x = 0; when a comparator is created by the constructor with a parameter x, it should compare quadraticFunction based on their values at x

Here's my code

I need help with part D, I don't know how to do some of it

```
    public class Ex4
    {
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;

 public Ex4(int x, int y, int z)
 {
    a = x; b=y; c=z;
 }
 public String toString()
 {
    String X="";
    X= X+a+"x^2"+b+"x"+ "+" + c;
    return X;
 }
 public double valueAt(double x)
 {
    return (a*x*x+b*x+c);
 }
 //////// Part B
 public boolean equals( Ex4 qf )
 {
    return(this.a==qf.a && this.b==qf.b && this.c==qf.c);
 }
 /////Part c
//   public int compareTo(Ex4 other)

//   {

//      if (a.equals(other.a))
//      {

//          if (b.equals(other.b))

//              return c.compareTo(other.c);

//          return b.comapreTo(other.b);

//          }

//    return a.compareTo(other.a);

//  }

public int compareTo(Ex4 other)
{
    if (a > other.a)
        return 1;
    else if (a < other.a)
        return -1;
    else if (b > other.b)
        return 1;
    else if (b < other.b)
        return -1;
    else if (c > other.c)
        return 1;
    else if (c < other.c)
        return -1;
    else
        return 0;
}
////Part d

 public static void main(String[] args)
 {
    System.out.println(new Ex3(1, -5, 6));
 }
}
```

Also in the uncomment the area of code under part c, it says int cannot be dereferenced on line 29, 31, 32,33, and 35
Thanks for the help

Comment: I hope this is a good place to start about comparator

Comment: `Always` override `hashcode()` when you override `equals()`.

Comment: RE: `a.equals(other.a)`: `equals` is for objects; it lets you compare two objects for semantic equality rather than identity. Two primitives are equal if and only if they're identical, so you can just write `a == other.a`.

Answer (score 0):

You can't call methods on primitives, plain and simple.

A better option is to use Integer's static method, `Integer.compare(int a, int b)` to compare two ints.

Answer (score 0):

First, writing a custom [Comparator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) isn't too terribly difficult; you need to understand the basic structure of one.

Here's the idea:  it reads kind of like you're writing a `Comparable` entity.

```
class CustomComparator implements Comparator<Ex4> {

    @Override
    public int compare(Ex4 left, Ex4 right) {
        // Compare the entities as specified by the assignment
    }
}
```

Then, you need to accept that as a constructor argument.  That, I leave as an exercise to the reader.

Now, to the syntax issue:  you're treating primitive `int` as an `Integer`, which *does* have an `equals` method on it.  Primitives aren't objects, hence they can't be dereferenced.  You'll want to use the normal equivalence operators (`==, >, <`) in this  situation.  You have this already solved in your second-defined `compareTo` method.

**EDIT**:  After re-reading your requirements, I'm starting to think that your primitive fields are not the right way to go.  You should:

- Change your fields from `int` to `Integer`
- Implement `Comparable<Ex4>` on your entity class
- Rely on the default behavior of `compareTo()` for `Integer`; that is, your commented code  should "just work" (save for the misspell when comparing against C)
- Move the secondary `compareTo` to its own `Comparator` entity, as described above.

Comment: I don't think I misread part D on the assignment.  From what I'm reading, it sounds like the object should implement `Comparable` on some default comparison logic, *and* implement the custom `Comparable` to only compare on the X values.

Comment: I think the wires are getting crossed here.  For starters, I'm not seeing `Ex4` implement `Comparable`, which **is** what the assignment calls for.  The second `compareTo` method *does* exactly what part C asks, which is why part D requires the custom `Comparator` (you can't have two different `compareTo` methods in the same class that take the same arguments).  Hence, I'm still confused as to why you think that it's not about the `Comparator` interface...?

Comment: @ABoschman I don't see how this answer is wrong. Sparse maybe but this is a homework question and I wouldn't fault the answer for being incomplete. The spec for part D of the assignment is to create a Comparator.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
import java.util.Comparator;
public class Ex4Comparator implements Comparator<Ex4> {
    private double x = 0.0;

    public Ex4Comparator() {
    }

    public Ex4Comparator(double x) {
        this.x = x;
    }

    @Override
    public int compare(Ex4 o1, Ex4 o2) {
        return Double.compare(o1.valueAt(x), o2.valueAt(x));
    }
}
```

Also your equals method doesn't override Object's equals method. You may want to change it to something like

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (o instanceof Ex4) {
        Ex4 other = (Ex4)o;
        return (a == other.a && b == other.b && c == other.c);
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Ugh, don't just do their homework for them. Instead, give explanation and leave some implementation up to them.